# bidirectional named pipe question

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, named-pipes, bidirectional

I have 2 apps that I want to make communicate via named pipes on .NET 3.5.  Its a request/response paradigm, with the data transmitted as XML to make my life easier.  There is a listener app, and an app that posts requests to the pipe.  I'm trying to use a bidirectional pipe to do this.  The problem i have is that the call to StreamReader.ReadToEnd() doesnt seem to return.  What can I do to fix this?

Listener code

```
public Class Listener
{
    private void ThreadFunc()
    {
       var pipe = new NamedPipeServerStream("GuideSrv.Pipe",PipeDirection.InOut);
       var instream = new StreamReader(pipe);
       var outstream = new StreamWriter(pipe);
       while (true)
       {
           pipe.WaitForConnection();
           var response = ProcessPipeRequest(instream);
           outstream.Write(response.ToString());
           pipe.Disconnect();
       }
    }
    private XDocument ProcessPipeRequest(StreamReader stream)
    {
        var msg_in = stream.ReadToEnd();  // << This call doesnt return
        var xml_in = XDocument.Parse(msg_in);
        // do some stuff here 
        return new XDocument(....);
    }  
}
```

Requester code

```
public XDocument doIt()
{
    var xml = new XDocument(....);
    using (var pipe = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "GuideSrv.Pipe", PipeDirection.InOut))
     {
        using (var outstream = new StreamWriter(pipe))
        using (var instream = new StreamReader(pipe))
        {
            pipe.Connect();
            outstream.Write(xml.ToString());
            xml = XDocument.Parse(instream.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
    return xml;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you do `outstream.Write(xml.ToString())` in `doIt()` you then try to read from `instream`. Meanwhile your other thread is waiting in `stream.ReadToEnd()`. It will wait forever because it doesn't know that you're done writing. As far as it knows you could very well call `outstream.Write()` again to write some more data. The `ReadToEnd()` call is not going to return until you actually close the pipe from `doIt()`.

You can work around this by making them communicate with each other a little bit more intelligently. You could, for example, write the length of `xml.ToString()` to the pipe and then write the string. Then in your reader thread you first read the length and then read `msg_in`, only reading exact number of bytes you expect to be sent, stopping as soon as you read them all rather than waiting for the pipe to be closed.