# Ressource Handling for Streams operating on the same Pipe

Tags: .net, named-pipes, using-statement

First I write to a NamedPipeClientStream, then I read from it. This basically works. But I don't get the ressource handling of the StreamReader and StreamWriter right.

**Approach 1**

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pipeStream))
{
  // ...
  using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeStream))
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

The disposal of `sw` fails, because the stream has already been closed.

**Approach 2**

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pipeStream))
{
  // ...
}
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeStream))
{
  // ...
}
```

Now the pipe server in another process struggles, because the pipe connection was closed prematurely.

**Approach 3**

In [another question regarding file streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309062/bidirectional-named-pipe-question) it was suggested to use a separate stream for Reader and Writer. But this cannot be applied, since both shall use the same pipe instance.

So how are the streams managed correctly in this situation?

Comment: Yes, the StreamReader/Writer.Dispose() method will close the pipe stream.  This is rarely what you want, do not use the *using* statement.  Neither class has any other resources that require disposing.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a `FileStream` that can handle both reading and writing to a single stream?